# Backtesting for Vanguard Mutual Fund investments

Tags: mutual-funds, vanguard, backtesting

I'm new to this so my apologies if this is out of place or not a "correct" use of backtesting.

Is there a free service (or python package) for backtesting investment strategies for Vanguard mutual funds?

I have an automatic investment that occurs monthly but I'm curious how it would have improved (or not) over the past 12 months if I had contributed every 2 weeks instead of once per month.

As an example with fake numbers, what would the difference be over the past 12 months between contributing $1000 every month versus $500 every 2 weeks to VFINX?

Comment: Have you tried pulling data from the usual sources? Yahoo or Google? And then a simple spread sheet?

Comment: I pulled the data for 2016 from Yahoo and used a spreadsheet to manually calculate the differences (without accounting for dividends).  It looks like the Python `backtrader` module will make the process a bit more repeatable.

Comment: You might want to check out [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/backtest-portfolio

In the few cases I've manually tested it out using code, it seems to be accurate..